# Multiplying numbers in-place in a file

Tags: shell, text-processing, files, awk

I have ASCII file contain numbers as follow:

```
1 2 3
5 6 9
7 8 9 
. . . 
. . . 
. . . 
. . . 
. . .  etc
```

I want to upgrade this file by multiplying each value by "3" to get :

```
3 6 9
15 18 27
21 24 27 
. . . 
. . . 
. . . 
. . . 
. . .  etc
```

**I want these changes to be updated and saved automatically in the same ASCII file after running the script**

How can I accomplish this using standard GNU utilities? 
I can update the values by doing:

```
while IFS=",$IFS" read d1 d2 d3; do 
echo $(( $d1*3 )) $(( $d2*3 )) $(( $d3*3 )) 
done < file.txt #file.txt is the previous ASCII file
```

Comment: Are the input numbers all individually less than 10?

Comment: Also, bash is a shell, not a text processor. What other tools are acceptable? Standard GNU utilities?

Comment: It'd be good to have representative data in the Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can save new values to file:

```
awk -F" "  '{$1*=3;$2*=3;$3*=3;print}' FILE | tee FILE
```

Comment: I assume that destroys content of FILE.

Answer (score 3):

use awk:

```
$awk -F" "  '{$1*=3;$2*=3;$3*=3;print}' FILE | sponge FILE
$cat FILE
3 6 9
15 18 27
21 24 27
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

update:
you can use `sponge` program to write output in input FILE

> sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
>   Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening
>   the output file. This allows constricting pipelines that read from and
>   write to the same file.

Comment: @goro : UPDATED :)

Comment: if you don't have sponge, you can redirect output to a temporary file and then replace the original file with th the temp file (e.g. with `mv` or `cp` or `cat tempfile > originalfile`, etc)