# How to multiply two columns in a file by a constant number

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, numeric-data

I have a file like this.

input data

```
4.2394 4.4569
4.2427 4.1011
4.2879 4.1237
4.2106 4.4844
4.2373 4.1071
4.1322 4.0502
4.3103 4.4255
4.4342 4.5262
```

I need to multiply each element by a constant factor (in this example the factor is 8.06573) to produce an output like this:

output

```
34.193855762    35.948152037
34.220472671    33.078365303
34.585043667    33.260650801
33.961562738    36.169959612
34.176917729    33.126759683
33.329209506    32.667819646
34.765716019    35.694888115
35.765059966    36.507107126
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289188/multiplying-numbers-in-place-in-a-file?rq=1 is similar, but doesn't change the precision as you've indicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want; it accepts an awk variable named "factor" that is can easily be set to whatever you want:

```
awk -v factor=8.06573 '{printf "%2.9f %2.9f\n", $1 * factor, $2 * factor}'
```

With the given input, it outputs:

```
34.193855762 35.948152037
34.220472671 33.078365303
34.585043667 33.260650801
33.961562738 36.169959612
34.176917729 33.126759683
33.329209506 32.667819646
34.765716019 35.694888115
35.765059966 36.507107126
```